# How to convert a string to datetime

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a string like 'Jul 18, 2013 11:06:23 AM'
I want to display it like '07/18/2013 11:06:23 AM'
I try to to use To_date function (oracle function) to convert it, however I got error.
Please help me!

Comment: what you tried, what error you got

Comment: I wrote TO_DATE(myString, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM/PM'). I got ORA-01810: format code appears twice

Comment: the format will be `TO_DATE(myString, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')` not `TO_DATE(myString, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM/PM')`

Comment: i changed and got ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Since you want to display and have not logic or calculation on it. It is wise to use TO_CHAR than TO_DATE
to_char(#date#, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') where #date# is the column name of 'Jul 18, 2013 11:06:23 AM'

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it works very well:

```
select to_char(to_date('Jul 18, 2013 11:06:23','MON DD, YYYY HH:MI:SS',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') from dual
```

You can adapt to your problem.

Comment: Might be helpful to explain what the two functions and their format models are doing, and why the NLS override is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the following conversion function

```
to_date(mystring, 'Mon DD, YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

where your string is like in the above format, you have to use the format string based on your input string.

If you want to display the date in above format you have to use `TO_CHAR` function like below

```
select to_char(mydate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') from yourtable
```

check here for more information http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

Comment: you must specify the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE